# Executing javascript command that causes a redirect using a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarklet

I'm trying to create a javascript bookmarklet that will execute four commands on a web-application.

```
tabClick('1');
document.getElementById('2').click();
document.getElementById('3').click();
tabClick('4');
```

Right now, `tabClick('4')` or any function below the 3rd line will not execute. I think it's because `document.getElementById('3').click();` causes a redirect, which seems to wipe the bookmarklet.

Is there any way to have the bookmarklet continue to run code on the next page after the redirect?

Also, I'm currently just using setTimeout to pause for a second to wait for each command to load before doing the next like so:

```
javascript:tabClick('1');setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("2").click();},2000); setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("3").click();},3000);
```

Is there a way to tell the code to run the next line whenever the previous line has finished loading?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, what you can do is create a queue object in the window that executes the commands in the queue when the page is loaded.

But why would you click on two other elements when the second command is redirecting the page? If it's important I would recommend to change the sequence of the current commands executed.

Comment: I can't understand how the web application works, but not all functions are loaded on the page. You enter a value in a field. The first line takes you to a different view, the second opens up a menu which is only visible at that view, the third clicks a value in the menu which is now accessible, and the fourth takes you to yet another view. I'm simulating mouse clicks sequentially.

Comment: But javascript executes command in the sequence as defined. If you stay on the same page the commands would be executed. But when the page is loading a new view then all the command after this will not be excecuted. Is it possible to see it in action?

Comment: Afraid not, but I'll work on creating a queue object.

Comment: @crclayton "create a queue object in the window that executes the commands in the queue when the page is loaded" - I am fairly knowledgeable about JS and I have no idea what this means. A cursory Google search didn't help. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You can create a queue like solution in javascript. The window objects always stays intact so i you add an array to the window object you can reach the array on each page. This way you can add actions to the queue array and execute them on body load. This way all you actions will be executed